# Multivariate Newton Method Python Program

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a python program to calculate 4 unknowns (x, y, z, d) given a system of 4 non-linear equations. I am using the multivariate newton method.

However, the problem I have at the moment is that when I start my program, I do not get any output. The program runs (red square is going), but nothing is outputted.

There are some holes perhaps in my program, was hoping you could give some pointers.

Many thanks.

```
from autograd import jacobian
import autograd.numpy as np    
import numpy.linalg 
import sys 

tolerance = 0.0001    
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000);

def functionmatrix(x0):
    f1 = pow((x0[0] - 1560), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 6540), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 20140), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07074 - x0[3]), 2))
    f2 = pow((x0[0] - 18760), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 2750), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 18610), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07220 - x0[3]), 2))
    f3 = pow((x0[0] - 17610), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 14630), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 13480), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07690 - x0[3]), 2))
    f4 = pow((x0[0] - 19170), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 610), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 18390), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07242 - x0[3]), 2))
    functionmatrix = np.array([f1, f2, f3, f4]).reshape(4,1)
    return functionmatrix
 
def jacobianmatrix(x0):
    f1 = pow((x0[0] - 1560), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 6540), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 20140), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07074 - x0[3]), 2))
    f2 = pow((x0[0] - 18760), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 2750), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 18610), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07220 - x0[3]), 2))
    f3 = pow((x0[0] - 17610), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 14630), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 13480), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07690 - x0[3]), 2))
    f4 = pow((x0[0] - 19170), 2) + pow((x0[1] - 610), 2) + pow((x0[2] - 18390), 2) - (2.9*10**3*pow((0.07242 - x0[3]), 2))
    jacobianmatrix = np.array([jacobian(f1), jacobian(f2), jacobian(f3), jacobian(f4)]).reshape(4,1)
    inversejacobian = np.linalg.inv(jacobianmatrix)
    return inversejacobian

def determinevalues():
    euclideandistance = 100
    iteration = 0
    tolerance = 0.00000001
    maxiterations = 1000
    x0 = np.array([0,0,6370,0], dtype = float).reshape(4,1)
    while(np.any(abs(euclideandistance) > tolerance) and iteration < maxiterations):
        outputfunctionmatrix = functionmatrix(x0)
        outputjacobianmatrix = jacobianmatrix(x0)
        newxvalues = x0 - np.linalg.solve(outputfunctionmatrix, outputjacobianmatrix)
        iteration = iteration + 1
        x0 = newxvalues
        euclideandistance = np.linalg.norm(newxvalues - x0)

def main():
    determinevalues()
    
main()
```

Comment: use a debugger and see where it's stuck

Comment: Thanks for reply! How do I do this? Sorry if stupid question.

Comment: There are a couple of flaws in your code. I think you should carefully read it through and check it for problems. Things I've noticed: 1) you define the equations twice (the `equation*()` functions, and in `functionmatrix()`. This is poor coding style because it is very error prone! Indeed, the functionmatrix is inconsistent with the values specified in `equation*()`. (2) `np.linalg.multi_dot()` should be called as `np.linalg.multi_dot((mat1, mat2))`. (3) Several coding style issues, with no functional impact here, but it cause problems in other occasions...

Comment: You may find the symbolic math toolbox [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#a-more-interesting-example) useful. This way, you'd have to define the equations once, and could evaluate the Jacobian based on those.

Comment: 'functionmatrix is inconsistent with the values specified in equation*()"- I am not sure what you mean by this line?

Comment: Your function `jacobianmatrix` is wrong. You can't use the `autograd.jacobian` like this, please see [How to use Autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#how-to-use-autograd). Moreover you will find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) a little reminder how to calculate your Jacobian matrix. Typically you will need to calculate the gradient first and transpose it for each function to finally put in  a `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

I run it in my side and the `determinate()` function cause an error due to the recursion. But, there are also many things to work on.

First, you should used appropriated librairies, the Harvard autograd library ([link](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd)), has already grad and jacobian implementation. You problem can be simply resolve with this sample ([link](https://gist.github.com/lanius/bc70d601359ccbfbe45d)) :

```
import autograd.numpy as np
import autograd

def newton(f, x0, tol=0.0001, maxiter=10000):
    g = autograd.jacobian(f)
    h = autograd.hessian(f)

    x = x0
    for _ in range(maxiter):

        # ==========================
        # EDITED
        gx = np.squeeze(g(x))
        hx = np.squeeze(h(x))

        delta = np.linalg.multi_dot([np.linalg.inv(hx), gx])
        # ==========================

        x = x - delta
        if np.linalg.norm(delta) < tol:
            break

    return x


def main():

    def f(x):
        return np.array([[(x[0] - 1560) ** 2 + (x[1] - 6540) ** 2 + (x[2] - 20140) ** 2 - (2.9 * 10 ** 3 * (0.07074 - x[3]) ** 2)],
                        [(x[0] - 18760) ** 2 + (x[1] - 2750) ** 2 + (x[2] - 18610) ** 2 - (2.9 * 10 ** 3 * (0.0722 - x[3]) ** 2)], 
                        [(x[0] - 17640) ** 2 + (x[1] - 14630) ** 2 + (x[2] - 13480) ** 2 - (2.9 * 10 ** 3 * (0.0769 - x[3]) ** 2)],
                        [(x[0] - 19170) ** 2 + (x[1] - 610) ** 2 + (x[2] - 18390) ** 2 - (2.9 * 10 ** 3 * (0.07242 - x[3]) ** 2)]])              

    x0 = np.array([0., 0., 6730., 0.])

    print(newton(f, x0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Since you are in matrix alegra not linear, you just need to replace `autograd.grad(f)` by `autograd.jacobian(f)`. I don't know if the system will converge though! You could rebuild jacobian and hessian function if you want to do it yourself.

EDIT :

There is an error in my code, jacobian and hessian need be reshaped before the calculation and we need to use, as you already used in your previous code, `np.linalg.multi_dot()` function.

Comment: So i have edited my code, but now the error i get is "last 2 dimensions of the array must be square" Not sure what is going on. It must be square right, 4 equations, 4 solutions

Comment: cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Check the shape of your result. For me one dimension has been add with the autograd functions. To avoid this problem you should use `np.squeeze()`.

Comment: Not sure where i need to add the squeeze commands in my code.

Comment: Ok so i looked a bit closer and there seems to be a problem with my jacobian part. I can print out ok my function matrix, but my jacobian gives me this error: <function unary_to_nary.<locals>.nary_operator.<locals>.nary_f at 0x0000028FCE1D6F70>
<function unary_to_nary.<locals>.nary_operator.<locals>.nary_f at 0x0000028FCE1D6820>

Comment: So i have just done the jacobian manually and now I can print out both the function and jacobian arrays using my initial try. But when I start putting everything into my loop - i end up with "1 dimensional array given. Array must be at least two dimensional"

Comment: I have added some new code, if you could try to run it. Might help show the problem I am having

Comment: Unfortunately I am not available until Monday. I will take a look at your edited code. Your code seems much more complete than the last time. For dimensional problems don’t hesitate to print out the matrix dimension it helps to understand your error.